# Why do left join results not match in the MS Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, ms-access-2010

Why do left join SQL query results not match in the MS Access database?

Maybe there is something wrong with the SQL code that I wrote?

If there is an answer then I don't want to use the function in MS Access because I want to use the SQL for VB.Net.

Table `StocksinDetail`

| No | Invno | CodeProduct | Barcode | Colorcode | Size | Colorname | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITO-00004 | TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | - | - | 50 |
| 1 | ITO-00001 | TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | S | - | 50 |
| 2 | ITO-00001 | TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | BHTF001 | XL | Putih | 50 |
| 3 | ITO-00001 | TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | BHTF002 | M | - | 50 |
| 4 | ITO-00004 | TEST 1001 | 03-22164010 | BHTF001 | - | Putih | 50 |
| 1 | ITO-00005 | TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | - | - | 50 |

Table `StocksoutDetail`

| No | Invno | CodeProduct | Barcode | Colorcode | Size | Colorname | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITO-00001 | TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | S | - | 1 |
| 2 | ITO-00001 | TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | BHTF001 | XL | Putih | 1 |

Table `Stocksfinal`

| CodeProduct | Barcode | Colorcode | Size | Colorname | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | - | - | 50 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | - | - | 50 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | S | - | 50 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | BHTF001 | XL | Putih | 50 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | BHTF002 | M | - | 50 |
| TEST 1001 | 03-22164010 | BHTF001 | - | Putih | 50 |

Desired result

| CodeProduct | Barcode | Colorcode | Size | Colorname | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | - | - | 100 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | S | - | 50 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | BHTF001 | XL | Putih | 50 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | BHTF002 | M | - | 50 |
| TEST 1001 | 03-22164010 | BHTF001 | - | Putih | 50 |

```
SELECT  
    t1.CodeProduct, t1.Barcode, t1.Colorcode, t1.Size, 
    t1.ColorName,
    IIf(IsNull(t1.Qty),'0',t1.Qty)-IIf(IsNull(t2.Qty),'0',t2.Qty) AS QTY_STOCK,
    t1.Qty AS QTY_STOCKIN, t2.Qty AS QTY_STOCKOUT
FROM
    StocksinDetail AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    StocksoutDetail AS t2 ON (t1.Size = t2.Size)
                          AND (t1.Colorcode = t2.Colorcode)
                          AND (t1.Barcode = t2.Barcode)
                          AND (t1.CodeProduct = t2.CodeProduct);
```

Comment: Do you have a master table of all valid combinations of item characteristics? One that doesn't allow missing characteristics? The `-` values seem problematic, essentially nulls.  Also, I don't think you need single quotes around `0` in your sql statement.

Comment: @bugdrown , `Do you have a master table of all valid combinations of item characteristics?` I only have a master table ie `CodeProduct,Barcode` from transactions `StocksinDetail` then it will create a table `Stocksfinal` 
which will create from these 4 fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired result doesn't show any data from StocksoutDetail. The output can be obtained with an aggregate query of StocksinDetail alone (Query1 below). If you want to pull data from both tables as shown in your SQL statement, build aggregate queries of each detail table then join those queries.

Consider:

Query1: **SumIN**

```
SELECT CodeProduct, Barcode, Colorcode, Colorname, Size, Sum(Qty) AS SumINQty
FROM StocksinDetail
GROUP BY CodeProduct, Barcode, Colorcode, Colorname, Size;
```

Query2: **SumOUT**

```
SELECT CodeProduct, Barcode, Colorcode, Size, Sum(Qty) AS SumOUTQty
FROM StocksoutDetail
GROUP BY CodeProduct, Barcode, Colorcode, Size;
```

Query3:

```
SELECT SumIN.*, SumOUTQty, SumINQty - Nz(SumOUTQty,0) AS StockQty
FROM SumIN LEFT JOIN SumOUT 
ON (SumIN.Size = SumOUT.Size) AND (SumIN.Colorcode = SumOUT.Colorcode) 
AND (SumIN.Barcode = SumOUT.Barcode) AND (SumIN.CodeProduct = SumOUT.CodeProduct);
```

| CodeProduct | Barcode | Colorcode | Colorname | Size | SumINQty | SumOUTQty | StockQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | - | - | 100 |  | 100 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | - | - | S | 50 | 1 | 49 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | BHTF001 | Putih | XL | 50 | 1 | 49 |
| TEST 1000 | 03-22164010 | BHTF002 | - | M | 50 |  | 50 |
| TEST 1001 | 03-22164010 | BHTF001 | Putih | - | 50 |  | 50 |

If you want to make it an all-in-one SQL, copy/paste SQL of each aggregate query (without semicolon) into 3rd query - resulting **FROM** clause would be like;

```
FROM (paste query1 here) AS SumIN LEFT JOIN (paste query2 here) AS SumOUT
```

Then can delete first 2 query objects. This is how to use Access query designer to create complex nested queries.

If details were in a single Transactions table with a field to designate if transaction were IN or OUT, one aggregate query would serve. So an alternative to the 3 queries is to build a UNION query that merges these 2 tables into a single dataset (as would be if they were one table to begin with) then use that query in another that aggregates.

```
SELECT CodeProduct, Barcode, Colorcode, Size, Colorname, 
   Sum(IIf(Cat="IN", Qty, 0)) AS StocksIN, 
   Sum(IIf(Cat="Out", Qty, 0)) AS StocksOUT, 
   Sum(Qty * IIf(Cat="OUT", -1, 1)) AS StocksFinal 
FROM
   (SELECT [No], Invno, CodeProduct, Barcode, Colorcode, Size, Colorname, Qty, "IN" AS Cat FROM StocksinDetail
    UNION SELECT [No], Invno, CodeProduct, Barcode, Colorcode, Size, Colorname, Qty, "OUT" FROM StocksoutDetail) AS DetailUNION
GROUP BY CodeProduct, Barcode, Colorcode, Size, Colorname;
```

Comment: sorry I was late responding to you. Your updated answer is perfectly . One more thing, if you can, bring up the qty from stockindetail and the qty from stockoutdetail from your last answer.

Comment: Your updated answer is perfect. thanks for the help